# Quickbooks PHP Integration error: "No registered functions for action: SalesOrderImport"

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are encountering an issue while exporting the invoice but are unable to identify the root cause or how to resolve it.

Message:

-2: No registered functions for action: SalesOrderImport

Description:

Error message received from application via getLastError(): -2: No registered functions for action: SalesOrderImport

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the root cause of this issue and fixed it by adding the following code to the `example_web_connector_import.php` file. I added a sub-array to the `map` array in this file:

```
QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_SALESORDER => array( '_quickbooks_salesorder_import_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_import_response' ),
```

Like this:

```
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_import_request', '_quickbooks_customer_import_response' ), 
    QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_SALESORDER => array( '_quickbooks_salesorder_import_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_import_response' ), 
    );
```